# Android Platform Backwards Compatible

Tags: android

I am importing an android app into Eclipse. I am receiving the following error

> Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8

I have installed Android 4.0.3 (API15). Do I also need to install Android 2.2(API8)?

Is Android 4.0.3 (API15) not backwards compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application that you are importing is built using the Google API which is different from Android SDK. You can change the build target and set it to use the newer Google API if you have it already installed. If it is not already installed, you can install it using the SDK Manager.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have installed the Google API for Android 4.0.3. I just installed Android 2.2 and it is compiling with no errors. I just don't understand why I need to install both API's. Or should i update the build target to the new API?

Comment: Google APIs is an add-on to Android SDK which provides several services offered by Google. More info at https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/